# replace spaces from single characters in a string

Tags: php, regex

replace spaces from single characters in a string

```
$string = "lorem ipsum dummy text, abc g m a i l test ki ll exi t test 123 1 2     3.";
```

I want following output

```
$string = "lorem ipsum dummy text, abc gmail test ki ll exi t test 123 123.";
```

Note:

> g m a i l convert into gmail
>
> 1 2   3 convert into 123

gmail and 123 and are the examples text.

Example Code:

```
$string = "lorem ipsum dummy text, abc g m a i l test ki ll exi t test 123 1 2     3.";

echo preg_replace('"/\s+(\d{1,1})\s+/"', '', $string);
```

Comment: Please, show us what you have  tried.

Comment: $string = "lorem ipsum dummy text, abc g m a i l test ki ll exi t test 123 1 2     3.";


echo preg_replace('"/\s+(\d{1,1})\s+/"', '', $string);

Comment: There does not seem to be any decernable logic to the requirement so this is goin to be difficult

Comment: my tried not working that's why I not added

Comment: we need to filter banned words and some time user apply like K I L L  instead of kill

Comment: If it worked you wouldn't need to ask this question. It's common to show your failed attempts. They help us in helping you and also remove the feeling that we do all the work instead of you.

Comment: I dont know about this, thanks for that

Comment: Thanks @Alon Eitan for editting

Comment: I recommend to do the other way around, which is you have a list of banned words, then you populate a list of banned words with space in the middle, otherwise it will be difficult.

Comment: Indeed, then you can also take into account k1ll ki11 ki|| etc etc.

Comment: Something like `str_replace(['g m a i l', '1 2 3'], ['gmail', '123'], $input)` might help to start with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex and replace it with what matched in group1 which is exactly one word character.

```
(?<=\b\w\b) +(\b\w\b)
```

This regex basically selects one or more space followed by exactly one word `\w` character and makes sure it is preceded by exactly one `\w` character and replaces it by the character matched in group1, which is just one word character.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RIeCO6/1)**

Sample PHP codes,

```
$string = "lorem ipsum dummy text, abc g m a i l test ki ll exi t test 123 1 2     3.";
echo preg_replace('/(?<=\b\w\b) +(\b\w\b)/', '$1', $string);
```

Prints this like you mentioned in your post for expected output,

```
lorem ipsum dummy text, abc gmail test ki ll exi t test 123 123.
```

Comment: Happy to help :)